# how to update gridview row using viewstate

Tags: asp.net

I am using a `gridview` with `viewstate`.
     here I want to update `gridview` row. The `gridview` contains 4 columns
     Insertion and deletion process are done. But I don't know how to update row with view state. can anyone help me??

```
        if (ViewState["PdataTable"] == null)
        {
            TempDTable.Columns.Add("QuestionID", typeof(string));
            TempDTable.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(string));
            TempDTable.Columns.Add("ColumnType", typeof(string));
            TempDTable.Columns.Add("OptionValues", typeof(string));
        }
        else
        {
            TempDTable = (DataTable)ViewState["PdataTable"];
        }
        DataRow row;
        row = TempDTable.NewRow();


        TextBox txtftrColName = (TextBox)GridViewColumns.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrColName");
        DropDownList DrpType = (DropDownList)GridViewColumns.FooterRow.FindControl("DrpType");
        TextBox txtValues = (TextBox)GridViewColumns.FooterRow.FindControl("txtValues");

        row["QuestionID"] = Qst3.Text;
        row["ColumnName"] = txtftrColName.Text;
        row["ColumnType"] = DrpType.SelectedItem.Text;
        row["OptionValues"] = txtValues.Text;

        TempDTable.Rows.Add(row);
        ViewState["PdataTable"] = TempDTable;
        this.GridViewColumns.Visible = true;

        GridViewColumns.DataSource = TempDTable;
        GridViewColumns.DataBind();
```